# Powershell - Copy directory and files from source folder to destination folder

Tags: powershell

I am working out a scenario using PowerShell.

As of now, I am trying to workout a scenario where I have a batch job which upon successful execution first creates a date folder for that particular day and then creates a .CSV file under. The folder structure than look like below.

`\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20200120\TestA.CSV`

when the job runs next day, it will create another folder and file like below.

`\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20200121\TestB.CSV`

This is how there have been so many folders already created in past.

My PS script is good to run daily after the batch job is completed. I read a date, append to path and it copies file from source to destination folder. But I want to enable my PS script to read all previous **date** folders created under

`\\Server\SourceA\Processed\`

Another tricky part is - under the date folder there is few other sub folders. I.e.

```
\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20191010\Log
\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20191010\Charlie
\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20191010\Alpha
\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20191010\Delta
```

among them, I only need to read files from `Log` folder only.
Hence, my actual source path becomes like

`\\Server\SourceA\Processed\20191010\Log\TestA.CSV`

Here is my script (which is static right now and unable to read past existing date folders).

```
$fullSourceFileName = "\\Server\SourceA\Processed\"
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
$fullSourceFileName = "$($fullSourceFileName)$($date)\Log

$destination = "\\Server\DestA\Processed\"
$destination = "$($destination)$($date)\"

get-childitem -path $fullSourceFileName -recurse | copy-item -destination "$($destinationFolder)$($date)\"
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know I can use foreach loop in Powershell.
So, here is the answer to read all dynamic date folder under my given path.
I hope this helps the community.

```
$fullSourceFileName = "\\Server\SourceA\Processed\"
$DirToRead = "\Log\"
$dates = Get-ChildItem -Path $fullSourceFileName -Directory
$destination = "\\Server\DestA\Processed\"

foreach ($date in $dates){
        $ActualPath = "$($fullSourceFileName)$($date)$($DirToRead)"
        if(!(Test-Path $ActualPath))
        {
             Write-Output $($ActualPath)$(" source path does not exist")
        }
        else
        {
             get-childitem -path $ActualPath -recurse | copy-item -destination "$($destinationFolder)$($date)\"
        }
        $ActualPath = ""
}
```